Ошибка Uncaught runtime errors: При загрузке сайта на сервер
После загрузки проекта React, mode.js, mongodb, на сервер, в мобильной версии выскакивает ошибка Uncaught runtime errors:
Script error.
handleError@https://astro-kovpan.com.ua/static/js/bundle.js:56124:67
@https://astro-kovpan.com.ua/static/js/bundle.js:5614

Нужно больше информации, например стек ошибки.
